# Database configuration

Tags: laravel, mongodb

Welcome 
I've got huge problem with Laravel framework and simple MongoDB setup...i just can't run now all commands like php artisan serve, make:Controller etc

'''
In ProviderRepository.php line 208:

Class 'Jenssegers\Mongodb\MongodbServiceProvider' not found
'''

This is error printed in console after running mentioned commands.

Mine configuration file .env

```
'''
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:kXYahE55R344r/s4JZveWi1b7ZZLLfrff+MpMfsSojM=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://localhost

LOG_CHANNEL=stack

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=laravel
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=

MONGO_DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
MONGO_DB_PORT=27017
MONGO_DB_DATABASE=mongocrud
MONGO_DB_USERNAME=
MONGO_DB_PASSWORD=
```

'''

I would be gratefull for assistance..

P.S. 
This is link for tutorial i have used

```
<https://appdividend.com/2018/05/10/laravel-mongodb-crud-tutorial-with-   example/>
```

Answer (score -1):

There could be few issues here. First one is, maybe you don't have the `Jenssegers\Mongodb` package, so you have to install it first:

```
composer require jenssegers/mongodb
```

If you already have the package, then clear your cache and dump composer autoload:

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:clear
composer dump-autoload
```

If the problem is still present, manually delete the Bootstrap cache from your app:

> bootstrap/cache/services.php

Comment: Exact duplicate of the existing answers. Please don't do that. If you find existing answers using a search engine, then suggest/mark the duplicate rather than simply copying the content and calling it your own response.

Comment: Not a duplicate at all. I had the same issue few days ago and I did these steps to resolve it. This answer was from my own experience.

Comment: Yet the blocks of text in "your answer" are exactly the same as what is marked there. ( right down to the formatting of a quotation ). Little too obvious to claim anything different.

Comment: Guys I dont like also whispering marketing but I have an issue..please :)

Comment: Above command doesnt also work